# Multiple Google Maps in one JS file

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-street-view

I am looking for a way to include multiple google maps (street view) that each have a different latitude/longitude into different parts of my website.

Currently I can get it working with one map in my js file, but do not know how to add a second and third map that can be called into another div with their own id's. Below is my code for one map, how can I include other maps with the same settings?

Thank you!

```
var     pano;
var     latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(34.067722,-118.28681);

var panoOptions = {
    position: latlng,
        pov: {
          heading: 18.669,
          pitch: 20.072,
          zoom: 0,
        },
        addressControl:false,
        linksControl: false,
        panControl: false,
        zoomControl: false,
        enableCloseButton: false,
        fullScreenControlOptions: false
    };

pano = new google.maps.StreetViewPanorama(
    document.getElementById('streetViewIndex'), 
    panoOptions);

window.setInterval(function() {
    var pov = pano.getPov();
    pov.heading += 0.2;
    pano.setPov(pov);
}, 10);
```

Comment: What are the other locations?  What are the element Ids of the HTML divs? Have you tried just duplicating the code that renders the street view on the page with different locations/div ids?  What trouble did you run into when you did that?

Comment: @geocodezip. The other locations would be locations that I choose from Google Street View that would have a separate latitude and longitude. Another element ID would be something like "streetViewPhoenix" for example. Which would be on the same page as the "streetViewIndex". I did try to duplicate all the code but it just made the first map not spin in a panorama anymore and the second map completely grey and didn't display anything. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution: use a class to indicate the elements for display; and an array of coordinates.

**code snippet:**

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

  function initialize() {
    var points = [
      new google.maps.LatLng(29.5524337, -95.0945819), // 1st div with class="streetview"
      new google.maps.LatLng(48.85837, 2.2944813),     // 2nd div with class="streetview"
      new google.maps.LatLng(40.6892494, -74.0445)
    ];
    var panoramaOptions = {
      pov: {
        heading: 0,
        pitch: 0,
        zoom: -1,
      },
      addressControl: false,
      linksControl: false,
      panControl: false,
      zoomControl: false,
      enableCloseButton: false,
      fullScreenControlOptions: false
    };
    var mapdivs = document.getElementsByClassName('streetView');
    for (var i = 0; i < mapdivs.length; i++) {
      panoramaOptions.position = points[i];
      var panorama = new google.maps.StreetViewPanorama(mapdivs[i], panoramaOptions);
    }
  }

  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

});
```

```css
.streetView {
  height: 200px;
  width: 400px;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div class="streetView"></div>
<div class="streetView"></div>
<div class="streetView"></div>
```